# Can't close license agreement dialog when running XCode 6 after installation

Tags: xcode, installation, xcode6

After installing XCode 6 and running it, the license dialog appears.
I click "Agree".
And it does... nothing. The dialog is still there.

Even if the dialog is active, I can still access Xcode menu.
But it crashes as soon as I try to use anything.

I've tried:

- closing/launching it again
- several reboot sequence after install/uninstall
- uninstalling XCode 5.1 (which I used recently for several apps with no problem)
- removing `~/Library` Xcode related files (preferences)
- safe boot mode
- using `xcodebuild -license` and validating license in console mode
- repairing permissions with diskutility
- running maintenance scripts
- tried creating another administrator account and test through it

Everytime the dialog appears, I cannot close it.

Found [same problem in the Apple developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/970137#970137) where the user successfully terminated the install by rebooting. It does not work on my configuration (Macbook Pro, OS X 10.9.3)

Can't wait to test Swift.
Anybody's having same problem?

Edit 06/19:
- Apple has flagged my reported bug as a duplicate (and closed it). Too bad we have no way to search for other bugs in their reporting system (and any comment, workaround, ...). Next beta is available, not yet installed but hope it's fixed.

Edit 06/20:
- Still the same problem with Xcode 6 beta 2 :-(

Comment: Bug submitted to Apple. Hope it will be fixed in next beta or workaround... anyone suffering the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of pain, the problem finally seems simple enough. It's coming from the flags set on the plist file containing the Xcode license data. Open a terminal and check it:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ johnny$ ls -lO /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel        uchg         456 Sep 14  2013 com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

During license agreement, the annoying flag "uchg" prevents Xcode to update the file. If set, just run the following command in the terminal to unset the flag:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ johnny$ sudo chflags nouchg /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
```

You can then launch Xcode 6 again and agreeing the license works.
Tested with Xcode 6 beta 2.

After more than 2 weeks, I can now test Swift !

Comment: Damn--nice catch! I managed to work around it by simply restarting everything.

Answer (score 8):

Here's that one liner you've been looking for:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful

Comment: Thanks, simple enough

Answer (score 0):

I'm suffering the same problem, exactly as you described. Thanks for the steps you took to try to resolve it. Now I won't have to do the same.

For the umpteenth time, I see Apple has failed in some basic way here.

I know some people have successfully installed this. My best guess right now is that I'm installing it on Mavericks and not Yosemite Beta. That comes from the fact the the three posts I saw where people commented positively also talked about Yosemite features.